# Connect to MongoDB for Audit Logging Module for My EF Core Project ABP Framework

Tags: abp

I made a project using ABP Framework Angular and EF Core as the DB Provider. How to connect to MongoDB specifically for the Audit Logging Module when the project is using EF Core as the DB Provider? I read the doc where we can differentiate connection strings by modules like "AbpAuditlogging":"localhost". but I notice that the package used for EF Core and MongoDB are different. What should I consider to change the Audit Logging for my EF Core Project to point to a MongoDB? is it possible?